# Forward generator to caller

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
def my_range(start, stop, step):
    for i in range(start, stop, step=step):
        yield i
```

How can I rewrite the above code so I don't have to (explicitly at least) loop through the inner generator yielding each item one-by-one?

Comment: return the same generator? `return range(start, stop, step=step)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply use the `yield from` statement to delegate the generator functionality to another iterable. In this case, it would be the built-in `range()` function. Here's the modified code:

```py
def my_range(start, stop, step):
    yield from range(start, stop, step)
```

Now you don't need an explicit loop for yielding the items of the `range()` generator one-by-one.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks, I specified "iterable" instead of "generator" now.